# Make a square flickering at a preset frequency

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I'm working on a medi-sci project where I want the patient to use brainwaves to exercise control the environment.

The environmnet is a 2D game where the game character is to be controlled by 2 flickering squares. Each square are supposed to be on different frequencies e.g. 7Hz and 9Hz. They should flicker between black and white.

These frequencies will be measured on the brain and used to move the characters in a BCI solution. The project is being made in Unity and in c#.

I tried to use the animator and the Update function in Unity to get a flickering but it didn't work out (Read: It was very bad) because when the game became slow so did the flickering. I couldn't use that.

A friend told me that there's a difference between CRT and LCD screens so the refresh rate is different and can't be used the same way. 
I was also told to look into Timer.Interval in C# (or just the Timer class) and use that to switch between black and white squares to get the right frequency.

Is there anyone who could show me how to do this the right way in unity with C#? 
I mean how can I use Timers.Interval or System.Timers.Timer (or something else in the Timer class) to give me the right frequency in Unity?

I would prefer an example because I can't see any way of getting to the solution at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off CRT and LCD are different in may ways. Though I'm not sure how their refresh rate changes. I can say, with absolute certainty, that their difference in refresh systems is not something that is used. Nor is it something that you can change, or something that will be effected by game-code (aside from maybe adjusting the refresh rate, if you felt like going to an extreme.) All you can do is pump out an image to it though the cable connected to your computer, after that all you can do is hope the monitor displays it.

If your pumping out images to fast for the monitor to display them, then it drops the frame. If your pumping out images slower than it's displaying them, then it continues to display the same frame (for a brief time.)

---

There are two options that I'm seeing:

1. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Delta time indicates the number of seconds that have passed between this frame and the last frame. Since it's a float variable, you can use it to determine the amount of time that has lapsed for your Hz cycle. This, however, is frame-rate dependent. Granted, if your game is going around 9Hz (which would be 9fps), it's not going to be playable anyway. Typically, you want a minimum of 20Hz before a game is considered playable.
30Hz is standard. 60Hz is ideal (It's the refresh-rate of most modern monitors.)

2. FixedUpdate() - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

FixedUpdate gets called every `x.y` seconds regardless of frame-rate (frame-rate might be sacrificed to ensure it.) Should be fairly reliable. You then have the problem, however, of if that frame gets rendered. Even if it updates, if your frame-rate is slow enough to skip an entire 9Hz cycle, you might not see it update. (But it will cycle regardless.)

---

**HOWEVER**,
I personally would say to figure out why your frame-rate is dropping low enough to make it problematic. There should be [diagnostic tools](http://www.paladinstudios.com/2012/07/30/4-ways-to-increase-performance-of-your-unity-game/) somewhere in unity, find your-self the bottlenecks and fix them. If the games becoming slow-enough to be visible in a 9Hz cycle, then it's a fairly major frame-rate drop.

---

Edit:

Okay, Here is the basic theory. You have Hz, Hz is a unit of measurement that records the number of cycles per second. So saying you want something to switch on and off at 9 Hz, means you want it to turn on and off 9 times a second.

So we need some way to express the on/off oscillation according to time. The easiest means of oscillation we have access to is a sine or cosine wave.

If we are to use that, we end up with a value that goes from 0, to 1, to 0, to -1, to 0...

However, we only need on and off. We don't need every value between -1 and 1. We can simplify it by saying "This half of the cycle means on, and this half of the cycle means off." To divide it into half, we'll use the value 0 as our switch point. Resulting in something like:

[image: a rendering of a 3 Hz sine wave with the positive colored black, and the negative colored white]

All this theory coming down to the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class flicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite white;
    public Sprite black;
    public SpriteRenderer ren;
    public float cycleHz; // Hz, the mesurement of cycles.

    float dtime = 0; // delta time

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // update frequency time-step
        dtime += Time.deltaTime;

        // Sample the waveform at a specific time.
        float wave = Mathf.Sin( (dtime * 2.0f * Mathf.PI) * cycleHz);

        print (dtime);
        print (wave);

        // Cycle between sprites based on the waveform.
        if (wave > 0.0f)
        {
            print ("Black");
        }
        else
        {
            print ("White");
        }

        // prevents dtime from climbing to infinity,
        // by stepping it back in the waveform to a point
        // of equal value.
        if (wave == 0.0f)
        {
            dtime = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus Fun:

- What happens when we make it so that the switch point is 0.5?
- What if it's cosine instead of sine?
- What happens if we make it *tangent* instead of sine or cosine?

Comment: I tried FixedUpdate it didn't work out either. I tried a print out which showed it was impossible. The 9Hz is not for the whole game but for the flickering square. The lagging came from the gameobjects in the game. The main player is trying to catch elements dropping from the sky and if there are a bit too many the game starts to go slow for a few secs or more which means the flickering does too. This is the reason why I'm seeking another way which works (like the Timer class from c#...) and hopefully it would work.

Comment: So the flickering code, as you have it, works fine. It's just that the game slows down when you are drawing to many elements to the screen?

Comment: `using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class flicker : MonoBehaviour {
 public Sprite white; 
 public Sprite black;
 
 public SpriteRenderer ren;   

 // Update is called once per frame
 void FixedUpdate () {
   if (ren.sprite == white) {
    ren.sprite = black;
    } else {
    ren.sprite = white;
  }
 
 }
}`

Comment: errr...dunno what happened above. Anyway that code is no go. One frequency and very simple code. Aye the game slows down.

Comment: The comments section doesn't accept newlines, but it kept the spaces for the indent, that's what happened there. Give me a few minutes, I need to work out the code an explanation as to why the code works, and why that code. You should look into how to prevent a mass of elements from lowering your frame-rate.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've tried to look at the code for a few hours now (even when to get something to each to get a break from it) but I don't understand it. I can see that you add deltatime to dtime to let dtime get bigger. (printing out deltatime only I can see that it starts on 0.2 and then fast go down to 0.0164-0.0166). I don't understand the wave formula except that we are dividing with cycleHz (which would be 9 in my case) to check where we are on the wave. If we are over 0.0f then it's time to turn black if not then it's white.(on/off) I didn't get why you had to reset dtime at the end either.

Comment: I tried running it where I exchanged the variable cycleHz with 9 and printed out deltatime, dtime and wave. I got the values 0.0164 to 0.0166 for deltatime but for dtime and wave I got 0. 
Could I please ask you to explain the code to me like was I an idiot? (Yep, feeling like one right now)

Comment: Sorry. Does it work as you wanted at least? Starting with Mathf.sin, that provides the oscillation. The formula within is A bit more complicated. I honestly don't entirely know myself. I could probably work though it, but I just found a few sources online that used that and went with it.

Comment: And the thing at the end is a little bit of safety. If we just keep adding more and more to dtime, then it eventually reaches infinity. However, If dtime == 0, then the whole terms within the sine formula becomes zero. Sin(0) == 0, so wave will be 0. so if wave == 0, then I know that I can set dtime to 0 without having sudden shifts in wave.

Comment: Sorry, I had my formula wrong. Adjusted now.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, I think the code does what it's supposed to do now. I counted the prints for black and white and while it shows 1 hertz less for the first second but the rest seems to be fine.(it goes back to the correct hertz on the rest of time.) I only tried up to 3-4 seconds and for 3, 7 and 9 but I'm guessing it's the same for the rest. I'll accept your solution. I can't measure the flickering until after a week but I think it will work, otherwise I will be back. Thanks very much for helping me out and bearing with my ignorance. Now I just hope this solution works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead-set on flickering, there's a simple solution to this, which is to use a trig/wave method (like `sin` or `cos`). These will produce a continuous, even oscillation (which, at a high enough frequency, may appear similar to flickering).

I don't know enough about Unity to suggest why it didn't work. What I think is that you're probably using total game time (instead of time since the last draw/update call), or your update interval (since the last frame) is too big.

If you decide to use trigonometric functions, you can just use something like the current time (total number of seconds since game start or some other date/time) as the value to pass into the sine/cosine method.

Comment: I can't use trigonometric since I need a frequency I can set. So if I want a frequency on 6 hz I should be able to set that for the flickering squares and should get that output from the squares when I measure the brainwaves from the patient.

Comment: A frequency of `6hz` means you iterate through `2pi * 6` every second. It shouldn't be hard to do that.